Adding Value to a new table from multiple tables
I have 4 tables name them as 1,2,3,4 in order. I have wrote join queries to join all four of them and get a resulted output. The resulted output is perfect.
Now, I have to take that output and put it into a new table what would be the best and efficient way to do that?
To clarify even further
Add Specific Columns of Table1, Table2, Table3, Table4 to entirely new Table5

You can do something as simple as like: CREATE TABLE Table5 AS SELECT ... FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 ON .... etc. In other words: CREATE TABLE Table5 AS [your query] (in mysql)

"To clarify even further..."  Swing and a miss.   Sample data, desired results (as text)  would be more helpful.

If you're using SQL Server, you can insert your results into a table with the into keyword. Here's an example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#a-creating-a-table-by-specifying-columns-from-multiple-sources

I've gone ahead and removed theconflicting tags; please [edit] your question to (re)tag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?

Have you considered creating a view instead?

Thank You All, would try getting better at posting my questions

First create a new table with the necessary columns and you can use the below query:
INSERT INTO new_table_name (column1, column2, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, ...
FROM table1
  JOIN table2 ON table1.column = table2.column
  JOIN table3 ON table1.column = table3.column
  JOIN table4 ON table1.column = table4.column;


It looks like you are looking for CREATE TABLE ... SELECT syntax. It is supported by MySQL, you should be able to use your query as is for it. Be mindful about time and locks if you attempt it in production environment, tho.
CREATE TABLE table_name AS SELECT ...

